# Not able to connect to Aws rds instance for MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to amazon cloud. I have gone through different posts in Stack Overflow but couldn't understand what is the problem exactly. I created my SQL db instance and status is available. Assigned security group. Inbound port number is 3306.when I am doing telnet  portnumber in commnad line, it is showing "connection to host lost" immediately.

I am trying to connect to rds using MySQL workbench. I want to create db, table and insert some data.

Can somebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default an RDS instance is only accessible from within your VPC. If you want to access it from outside your VPC you need to enable the "Publicly Accessible" flag on the RDS instance.